# Why do I have a read-only error in my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, syntax-error, readonly

I have a small slider in my website and it always worked perfectly but now I get this error:

> Syntax error: "myIndex" is read-only

This is my JavaScript code:

```
const myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
 let i;
 const x = document.getElementsByClassName(`slides`);
 for (i = 0;i < x.length;i ++) {
 x[i].style.display = `none`;
 }

 myIndex ++;

 if (myIndex > x.length) {
  myIndex = 1;
 }

 x[myIndex - 1].style.display = `block`;
 setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="home-slider">
  <img class="slides" src="assets/img/slide_1.jpg" alt="slide1">
  <img class="slides" src="assets/img/slide_2.jpg" alt="slide2">
  <img class="slides" src="assets/img/slide_3.jpg" alt="slide3">
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining `myIndex` with the `const` statement. `const` creates a constant; that is to say a value which cannot be changed after first being initialised.

The error is being thrown when executing `myIndex ++`, which attempts to increment the stored value.

Instead of `const`, use `let` or `var`:

```
let myIndex = 0;
```

---

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. **The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.**
>
> – [MDN's `const` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)